# Failed to load pre trained onnx models in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, onnx

This is my first time with ONNX models and I’m not sure if I’m having a newbie problem so sorry in advance!

I’ve just tried to load a couple of models and I have the same assert always:

```
[ERROR:0@0.460] global onnx_importer.cpp:1054 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::ONNXImporter::handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 3 inputs and 1 outputs: [Concat]:(onnx_node!Concat_2) from domain='ai.onnx'
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) Error: Unspecified error (> Node [Concat@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!Concat_2) parse error: OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) C:\GHA-OCV-2\_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\concat_layer.cpp:105: error: (-215:Assertion failed) curShape.size() == outputs[0].size() in function 'cv::dnn::ConcatLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'
> ) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::ONNXImporter::handleNode, file C:\GHA-OCV-2\_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp, line 1073
```

Both models come from https://github.com/PeterL1n/RobustVideoMatting and they are “rvm_resnet50_fp32.onnx” and “rvm_mobilenetv3_fp32.onnx”

Obviously I’m loading them with

```
robustNN = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(robustNNPath);
```

Thank you in advance for any tip!

Comment: undeclared crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/failed-to-load-pre-trained-onnx-models/11526

Comment: Sorry I don't get why that's a problem. This has been discussed before and it's said that this is not a problem on separated sites https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126920/does-a-dupe-on-another-non-se-so-site-warrant-a-vote-to-close

Comment: read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange do you now get why that's a problem? -- your link doesn't apply. you didn't duplicate on Stack Exchange sites. you haven't got a close vote either. what does apply is this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu